# 16.04 SSH connection refused: hunting down root-cause

Tags: 16.04, ssh

Symptoms: 16.04 refuses connection from Putty and replies to ping requests

[Remedies on askubuntu suggest installing:](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104659/ssh-connection-getting-refused)

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Before I do this, how can I verify that an install is genuinely needed: I'd like to verify that it is not a configuration obstacle or maybe a service needs to be turned on?  Is there a list of checks that can be performed?

Update: **Does this response indicate that the install is required?**

```
user@host:~$ apt-cache policy openssh-server
openssh-server:
  Installed: (none)
```

Diagnostic credit and thanks to muru:

```
user@host:~$ service ssh status
● ssh.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)
user@host:~$ service ssh start
Failed to start ssh.service: Unit ssh.service not found.
user@host:~$ apt-cache policy openssh-server
openssh-server:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.1
  Version table:
     1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
     1:7.2p2-4 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: `service ssh status`, `apt-cache policy openssh-server`, `service ssh start`

Comment: The information from your updated question states it clearly in English that you do not have installed ssh daemon (server). @muru should write the answer as the credits belong to him/her :).

Comment: I thought as much:  thanks for confirming. @muru: I would be happy to confer credit where credit is due

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to connect using SSH, you need to have SSH running on the target system. `service ssh status` shows that it doesn't even know of such a service and `apt-cache policy openssh-server` shows that it hasn't been installed at all (`Installed: (none)`). So, yes, you have to install it.